# SQL GROUP BY with aggregate

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

If I have a table Numbers with data:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| colA | colB | colC | colD |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |
|    1 |    2 |    9 |    5 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

and do:

```
select colA, colB, colC, MAX(colD) FROM Numbers GROUP BY colA, colB;
```

I believe that it should return row 2. It groups by `colA, colB` and picks the largest one in `colD`.

Unfortunately this doesn't work, because you also have to group by colC in order to return it.

Why? Is there another way to do what I am trying to do?

I want the row with same in `colA` and `colB` but the largest one in `colD`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to handle this. Perhaps the easiest is a `JOIN` against a subquery which does the `colA, colB` group, and finds the full corresponding row from that.

```
SELECT 
  tbl.colA,
  tbl.colB,
  tbl.colC,
  tbl.colD
FROM tbl JOIN (
  SELECT
    colA,
    colB,
    MAX(colD) AS maxD
  FROM tbl
  GROUP BY colA, colB
) g ON tbl.colA = g.colA AND tbl.colB = g.colB AND tbl.colD = g.maxD
```

Comment: Thanks, and thank you Benoit for refactoring the question :) If the column names are same on both, do one really have to name all "on":s ?

Comment: @Hamidam Yes you do need them all listed in the `ON` clause, as long as one of them is not a primary key. If for example `colA` was a unique key value, you could just do `ON tbl.colA = g.colA`, but since yours aren't unique you need to combine as many columns as necessary to make a unique value `colA, colB, MAX(colD)`

Comment: I am thinking about something our university teacher said ( long ago ) about if the names ( column names ) are the same in both than you do not need to. But unsure if that was with joins or something else, perhaps it was unions...

Comment: @Hamidam that sounds like its related to a `UNION` rather than a `JOIN`.  Anyway, it is always best to be as explicit as possible in SQL queries. Shortcuts are sort of discouraged when it comes to things like `SELECT *`.

Comment: I think not `NATURAL JOIN` is what was proposed but `JOIN ... USING (col1, col2, col3)`. That would have two advantages: a little bit more precise ("hey, db, join an these columns" vs. "hey db, join on some expression which I hope I did right") while showing full information what is going on.

Comment: @A.H.: The problem with `NATURAL JOIN` and `JOIN ... USING` is that you lose qualification for the source tables. In this example you should therefore do `SELECT colA, colB, tbl.colC, colD ... JOIN ... USING(colA, colB, colD)`. Natural join is equivalent to `USING(all columns that have same name)`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
 SELECT N1.colA, N1.colB, N1.colC, N1.colD
   FROM Numbers N1
   LEFT JOIN Numbers N2 ON N2.colA = N1.colA
                       AND N2.colB = N1.colB
                       AND N2.colD > N1.colD
  WHERE N2.colA IS NULL;
```

The LEFT JOIN will lookup for a row in the same table with same columns A and B, and greater column D. When no row is found then you've the maximal value in Column D.

This is technically the same as:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Numbers N
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
     ( SELECT NULL /* or whatever you want, doesn't matter */
         FROM Numbers
        WHERE colA = N.colA
          AND colB = N.colB
          AND colD > N.colD
     )
```

Note that you might want to add a `DISTINCT` if this returns dupe rows.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems of your query is that you want to show the value of codC but it's not on the group by part. To show the value without a agregate function it must be on the group by part. Therefore, to fix your query you can do something like this:

```
select n1.* from Number n1
inner join (select colA, colB, max(colD) as colD from Number GROUP BY colA, colB) n2 on n1.colA = n2.colA and n1.colB = n2.colB and n1.colD = n2.colD
```

It will select all rows with max(colD) for each colA and colB.